# how to filter dictionary vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I have a script which is giving as outcome dictionary. Initially income is a string with format a=abc, b=def, c1=ghj, c2=klm, d1=123, d2=456.

Script is creating dictionary

```
For i = 0 to Wscript.Arguments.Count - 1
myArray = split(Wscript.Arguments(i),"=",-1,1)
objDict.Add myArray(0),myArray(1)
```

I needed to add additional pair to dictionary like C=ghj, klm (combined c1 and c2) and D = 123, 456. As vbs dictionary cannot have an array as value I'm stacked as for now.

Is it possible to create new dictionary/array with using filter? And how to achieve the result needed?

For example I have a function

```
Sub attachmentf()
Dim i
Dim x
Dim y(1)
Dim z
Dim a
Dim b
Dim c
Dim d

a = objDict.Keys  
c=Filter(a,"attachment")
    For i=0 to 1 'ubound(c)
    d = objDict.item(c(i)) 
    y(i) = d
    wscript.echo y(i)
    dictResults.Add "ATTACHMENT", y(i)
    next
end Sub
```

it returns me array at echo step, but it's giving me error: it does not conform to standard key/value pair format, once I try add it to dictionary.
Also it didn't work if I try to use unound or not provide array size (eg Dim y())...any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> As vbs dictionary cannot have an array as value [...]

What makes you believe that?

```
>>> Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>>> d.Add "foo", Array("a", "b")
>>> WScript.Echo d("foo")(1)
b
```

Comment: oh, you are right...key won't be an array.
But still stacking with combining C and D..